# What do the boundary modules do in an IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit

I cannot understand what is the purpose of digital and analog boundary modules embedded in an IC for testing. What are their function?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean *boundary scan* modules?

Comment: The AMBs in the diagram.

Comment: What device is it?

Comment: It can be any IC/SoC. It is related to test bus architecture standard  IEEE 1149.4. Thats all I know,

Comment: No, please list the device part number because *It can be any IC/SoC* is clearly a misdirection because hardly any chips will have this type of internal format.

Comment: I see your point but it is a standard Im asking the part of functionality of that standard not a specific design. I ask it out of curiosity I dont have a particular chip. A novice question.

Comment: But **it is** a particular chip. It is a "Dot 4 test chip". So tell us everything you can about a "Dot 4 test chip". Otherwise the question is too vague to give a proper answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are basically switches that allow any two pins to be connected to the internal test buses AB<sub>1</sub> and AB<sub>2</sub> which are then brought out to the external pins AT<sub>1</sub> and AT<sub>2</sub> where they can be measured.

It's basically a huge internal analog multiplexer, eliminating the need to physically probe all of those pins individually in the test fixture.

As shown, the ABM probably includes the ability to disconnect each external pin from the corresponding core connection, and to probe either side of that connection.

Comment: text fixture or test fixture?

Comment: @pnatk: Thanks, fixed!